# Can you write a generic function that will compare any numeric type (e.g. int, float, double) against zero?

Tags: generics, swift4, comparable

We're trying to write a simple gain/loss function to return a color based on a value relative to zero.  If it's positive, we return green. If negative, we return red. If zero, we return gray.

The current function is written specifically to take a double, like so:

```
func getChangeColor(value:Double) -> UIColor {

    if value > 0 {
        return Theme.Colors.gain
    } else if value < 0 {
        return Theme.Colors.loss
    } else {
        return Theme.Colors.noChange
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering if it can be updated to take *any* numeric value?

My first thought was to write it against `Comparable` but the problem is we need to compare it against zero in that same type, whatever it is.

In other languages like C#, you can get the default value for a type, which in the case of numerics, is zero.  Does Swift have anything similar? If so, we could do this...

```
func getChangeColor<T:Comparable>(value:T) -> UIColor {

    let defaultValue = default(T.self)

    if value > defaultValue {
        return Theme.Colors.gain
    } else if value < defaultValue {
        return Theme.Colors.loss
    } else {
        return Theme.Colors.noChange
    }
}
```

...or is this approach wrong in the first place?

Comment: To the person who voted this down, mind explaining why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution adds a second protocol conformance: `Numeric` provides basic arithmetic operators for scalar types.

Then you are able to *calculate* the zero value in the generic type

```
func getChangeColor<T : Comparable & Numeric>(value:T) -> UIColor {

    let zero = value - value

    if value > zero {
        return Theme.Colors.gain
    } else if value < zero {
        return Theme.Colors.loss
    } else {
        return Theme.Colors.noChange
    }
}
```

or with a `switch` statement

```
func getChangeColor<T : Comparable & Numeric>(value:T) -> UIColor {

    let zero = value - value

    switch value {
    case zero:  return Theme.Colors.noChange
    case zero...: return Theme.Colors.gain
    default: return Theme.Colors.loss
    }
}
```

or with the ternary operator *(added by OP)*

```
func getChangeColor<T : Comparable & Numeric>(value:T) -> UIColor {

    let zero = value - value

    return value > zero
        ? Theme.Colors.gain
        : value < zero
            ? Theme.Colors.loss
            : Theme.Colors.noChange
}
```

Comment: First of all, that is *awesome* how you came to get your zero value!  Genius!  BUT... I thought the Swift numeric protocol didn't work for doubles and such. Am I wrong?

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I was reading the Swift evolution articles about it and they kept referring to it being for integer-types, but the documentation backs up what you're saying... any numeric type. Again, really great solution!  Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: It's odd that `Numeric` doesn't automatically conform to `Comparable` though.  That seems like an oversight on their part, no?

Comment: Feel free to file a bug or a proposal 

Comment: Just had to say again it's pretty awesome how you solved this problem, and how you came to get zero. It's so simple and elegant! Answers like this make my brain happy! :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I've been searching how to accommodate different numerical type for heap implementation and yours resolved my problem.